# AuthorizeAttribute. Grant access to some action in controller for different role

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

There are two roles in my application: `Admin` and `ContentMaker`. Admin has full access and ContentMaker can create\edit articles. One user has one role (one-to-one).
Although i have only one `AdminController` for all stuff (include manage articles) decorated with AuthorizeAttribute. I want to grant access only to edit articles for `ContentMaker` within AdminController. The problem is contentmaker IS NOT admin so he has no access to AdminController in all. Is it possible to extend AuthorizeAttribute to let this behavior? This is what i want:

```
//only Admin can access this controller
[Authorize(Roles = ConstantsWeb.Database.AdminRoleName)]
public partial class AdminController : Controller
{
    //ContentMaker has no access here
    public ActionResult SomeAdminStuffAction()
    {
        //code
    }

    //ContentMaker only has access here, although he is not Admin
    [Authorize(Roles = ConstantsWeb.Database.ContentMakerRoleName)]
    public ActionResult EditArticle(int id)
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy solution. Since ASP.NET MVC 5 here is `OverrideAuthorization` attribute. It let to override access permissions for any actions in controller. You need to put `OverrideAuthorization` attribute and another `Authorize` attribute. Like this:

```
//only Admin can access this controller
[Authorize(Roles = ConstantsWeb.Database.AdminRoleName)]
public partial class AdminController : Controller
{
    //ContentMaker has no access here
    public ActionResult SomeAdminStuffAction()
    {
        //code
    }

    //ContentMaker only has access here, although he is not Admin
    [OverrideAuthorization]
    [Authorize(Roles = ConstantsWeb.Database.AdminRoleName + "," + ConstantsWeb.Database.ContentMakerRoleName)]
    public ActionResult EditArticle(int id)
    {
        //code
    }
}
```